# Php Artisan Make Controller command throwing error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Hello guys I'm trying to run the make controller command but it throwing me an error. Here is the error

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
  Use of undefined constant CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST - assumed 'CURLE_COULD  
  NT_RESOLVE_HOST'
```

and here is the command that I'm trying to run

```
php artisan make controller PetsController --resource
```

I  have googled this issue what I got were solution for php Amazon sdk. Please tell me why am I facing this issue

Comment: Use : in command, like `php artisan make:controller PetsController --resource`

Comment: Is it solved???

Comment: Are you running your website through Vagrant or similar? Make sure you run your `php artisan` commands in the context of your server. That is, if you're using vagrant, SSH into your server first using `vagrant ssh` and then run your commands. Also, you're missing `:` between `make` and `controller`, it should be `php artisan make:controller PetsController --resource`

Comment: @HirenGohel Sorry for the late reply. but I have also tried the code that you suggested but that is not working also

Answer (score 3):

if you are using Linux version, try to use

```
sudo php artisan make:controller PetsController --resource
```

In windows, run CMD as Administrator.then execute

```
php artisan make:controller PetsController --resource
```

And make sure you are not having any errors in your `route.php`

Comment: @Garden , I think you should try this, this seems to be more perfect

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But this is also not working and @Nil I have trued this this is not working also

Comment: I  keep getting the same error. Can't understand why am I getting this error

Comment: are you running laravel server?

Comment: no I'm not running a laravel server. I running my project in homestead/laravel

Answer (score -1):

Try this to fix :

```
php artisan controller:make YourController
```